# Sybase "interfaces" file issue

Tags: sybase

There is a strange issue about sybase interfaces file.  We have an application which is run on solaris sparc OS and this application uses open client (sybase OCS-12_5) for database operations. When we upgrade our database server to sybase 15.03, our application didn't work. then I start the research for figure out why it does not work. End of the my research, i found the the reason is sybase15.03's interfaces file. Somehow,15.03's interfaces file is damaged i think. But sybase 12.5 interfaces file and sybase 15.03 interfaces file is same.I checked interfaces file for unknown character or carrige return character but there is no any strange character in it.  When I copied sybase12.5's interfaces file to sybase15 directory, application runs correctly. Is there anyone to explain this?

PS: Sybase libraries looks for $SYBASE env. variable and reads the $SYBASE/interfaces file for gather server information like server host and port

Thanks and regards.

Comment: if you have Sybase support, call them!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a minor error in the 15.0.3 interfaces file format.

Suggested approach to diagnosing:

- (Unix) `diff` the working and non-working interfaces files - if the servers they describe is the same the difference should be apparent pretty quickly.
- Check the format against the [rules in Sybase documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc35823_1500/html/uconfig/X42052.htm).

If the problem is still not manifest, then 'divide an conquer' might be the next step - try a smaller subset of the problem interfaces file.

Failing that, you could post equivalent entries from the two files here and see if the community can spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the space in between lines and make sure there is a extra empty line at the end of the interface file.

Another thing to make sure is the network setting you have choose. It should be the same. It would be most probably TCP. Some versions in 12.5 used to put other entries.

Another method to correct this is to use a DSCP method. This ensures that the interface file is correct.